# How can I create partition in a set using java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have index a set `{1,2,3,4,5}`. The decision variables outputs are:

```
x[1][2] = 0
x[1][3] = 0
x[1][4] = 1
x[1][5] = 1
x[2][1] = 0
x[2][3] = 0
x[2][4] = 1
x[2][5] = 1
x[3][1] = 0
x[3][2] = 0
x[3][4] = 1
x[3][5] = 1
x[4][1] = 1
x[4][2] = 1
x[4][3] = 1
x[4][5] = 0
x[5][1] = 1
x[5][2] = 1
x[5][3] = 1
x[5][4] = 1
```

Now I want to create partitions base on decision variable value. If `x[i][j]= 0` then `i` & `j` are in same set. That is the output of the above problem should two partitions: `{1,2,3}` and `{4,5}`.

How can I do it in java? Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Be more clear, write some code, propose your solution.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You forgot to describe what problem you are having. We know what you want to do, but we don't know what is stopping you.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, sorry I was out  of the network. I wrote the following code: 
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> partitions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
 ArrayList<Integer> thisPartition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int j=1; j<n; j++) {
  if( x[i][j] == 0) {
                     if (thisPartition.contains(j)) continue;
       else thisCluster.add(j);
  }
     }
     if (cluster.contains(thisCluster)) {
      continue;
     }
     else {
      cluster.add(thisCluster);
     }
    }
    System.out.println("Clusters: "  + cluster);

Comment: Do not put code in the comments. Always add relevant information to your original question, properly formatted.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic. I am very new in coding. Following solution given by saka1029 is working for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static <T> void partitioning(Set<Set<T>> partition, Set<T> set) {
    L: while (true) {
        for (Set<T> p : partition) {
            for (T e : set) {
                if (p.contains(e)) {
                    partition.remove(p);
                    p.addAll(set);
                    set = p;
                    continue L;
                }
            }
        }
        partition.add(set);
        return;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] x = new int[6][6];
    x[1][2] = 0;
    x[1][3] = 0;
    // .....
    x[5][4] = 1;
    Set<Set<Integer>> partition = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 1, is = x.length; i < is; ++i)
        for (int j = 1, js = x[i].length; j < js; ++j)
            if (x[i][j] == 0) {
                Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
                set.add(i);
                set.add(j);
                partitioning(partition, set);
            }
    System.out.println(partition);
    // -> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
}
```